# TensorFlow Install ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, gpu

System Specs

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install

Nvidia GPU: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2

Laptop: MSI gf63

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu, however I consistently keep getting this error.
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I followed this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/30/ubuntu-18-04-install-tensorflow-and-keras-for-deep-learning/) as my guide to installing tensorflow to the letter even taking care to install the Nvidia drivers they installed. However, I consistently got the error above. I am fairly new to this stuff so I would really hope any concise solution to my issue. Thanks.